# How to get the "Now" button the jQuery datetimepicker to close the widget, like the "Done" button does

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker, datetimepicker

I would like the "Now" button on the datetimepicker to close the widget when it's clicked. As it stands now the user has to click "Now" and the "Done".

My application has a great deal of timestamps so this ends up being tedious. Thanks.

Does anyone know if this is configurable or do I need to hack into the jQuery plugin code (Please say the former). Thanks.

Comment: if it's not configurable you could listen to the click on the "Now" Button and then trigger a click on the "Done" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event to trigger the done button (or close the dialog)

Comment: A colleague actually found the offending line of code (we updated our version and the behavior changed to what it was above; he looked through the commit and found the change) Thanks for the info, though. Got to get better at JS.

Comment: @steve_gallagher yea.. the new version of jQueryUI changed a lot of old code.. I ended up rolling back to just using the old version...

Answer (score 0):

I finished up on adding `closeOnNowClick` setting and changing `_gotoToday` in Trent's `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` (version 1.6.1):

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
    var inst = this._getInst($(id)[0]);

    // ***: added to hide dialog on Now click
    var closeOnNowClick = this._get(inst, 'closeOnNowClick');
    if (typeof(closeOnNowClick) == 'boolean' && closeOnNowClick === true) {
        this._hideDatepicker(); 
    }

    this._base_gotoToday(id);
    var tp_inst = this._get(inst, 'timepicker');
    var tzoffset = parseInt($.timepicker.timezoneOffsetNumber(tp_inst.timezone)); // ***: added parseInt here
    var now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + now.getTimezoneOffset() + tzoffset);
    this._setTime(inst, now);
    this._setDate(inst, now);
    tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
};
```

Sample usage:

```
$('#somedate')
    .datetimepicker({'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd',
    'timeFormat':'HH:mm',
    'timeInput': true,
    'closeOnNowClick': true
});
```

I also noticed that sometimes `tzoffset` is returned as string, and `now.getMinutes() + now.getTimezoneOffset() + tzoffset` results in absolutely weird values. So I have added the `parseInt` call to convert `tzoffset` to int.